# Copyright of similar domain names

Tags: domains, copyright

If I was to create a social network similar to Facebook that was much faster and offers other services that attract users and I bought a domain that is similar to Facebook.com, for example facebbok.com or fasebook.com. Would I be in trouble for copyright or other offences?

Comment: Yes. Yes you would.

Comment: compare the size of your bankroll to facebook.  The legal outcome hardly matters.  Can you afford to fight them?

Comment: Try being SparkFun.com who uses their website name under license from Oracle Corporation because Oracle owns Sun Microsystems and therefore the Sparc trademark. The legal beef came about because Spark, Sparc and things electronic were considered to be an appropriation of a registered trademark and therefore open to cease and desist until Oracle relented and gave them specific rights to use the "misspelling" of Sparc in their domain name. So, if you think you can get Facebook to license fasebook to you for running the exact same site, you have a lot of lawyer's fees in your future.

Comment: `fasebook.com` is already registered by Facebook Inc. `facebbok.com` is already registered by someone in New Delhi with a "great idea" and has probably already been served a cease and desist (there's no DNS). Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you'll be in trouble for making the difference in the domain name only by one or two characters. On top of that, you're trying to make a similar network which in effect means trying to copy the basic operation of facebook in general.

Why not make something brand new that hasn't been on the internet before and use a completely different domain name?

And if you must copy something from facebook, please read their terms and conditions first before going any further.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather malicious to do that. No, it's not exactly "illegal" because it is a different domain name, and you aren't stealing anything from facebook directly, but it certainly IS malicious. Also, yes, compare your bankroll to facebook. I highly doubt you could withstand them, even *if* your case was actually valid.